# Javascript, remove class of DIV based on value of Link's innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, class

I am looking for some help with Javascript. I have a piece of HTML as follows:

```
<div class="KeepShopping FloatRight GreenButton">
    <a href="http://www.xyz.com">Click here to keep shopping</a>
</div>
```

I am trying to remove class "GreenButton from the DIV once the link inside it has no text in the HTML, so the end result should look like this:

```
<div class="KeepShopping FloatRight">
    <a href="http://www.xyz.com"></a>
</div>
```

I have been unsuccessfully trying to get this with the following code, which runs at end of page load/refresh:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(".KeepShopping").each(function() {
    if($("a", this).html == "") {
        $(this).removeClass("GreenButtonLge");
    }
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions / ideas are really welcome! Thank in advance for any help!

Comment: write html() not html

Comment: You can also use $('.KeepShopping a:empty') to find the empty a tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`html` is a function, not a property. Write like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(".KeepShopping").each(function() {
    if($("a", this).html() == "") {
        $(this).removeClass("GreenButtonLge");
    }
});
</script>
```